# Adding HATEOAS to a Maven project with pre-existing Spring dependencies

Tags: spring, maven, hateoas

I am trying to add Spring HATEOAS to a Maven project with pre-existing Spring dependencies.  This immediately caused compile-time issues which I solved by adding exclusions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>0.19.0.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

However now I have a runtime exception caused by a missing class called PluginRegistry:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:487)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:428)
... 36 more
```

What is the missing dependency or dependencies that I need to add? Are they runtime or provided dependencies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

gradle:

```
'org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:1.2.0.RELEASE'
```

Comment: I added that dependency and now I get this:  
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.clearMetadataCache()V
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:673)

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Paolo you was very close, just add another exclusion of spring-core. This should solve problem.

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
<version>0.21.0.RELEASE</version><exclusions>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  </exclusion>      
</exclusions>
```

Hope it helps!!